# Python Create dataframe from nested dict with lists

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to create a dataframe / csv that looks like this

| App | id | stages | requestCpu | requestMemory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| appName | 123 | dev | 1000 | 1024 |
| appName | 123 | staging | 3200 | 1024 |

The dict data looks like this and includes quite a lot of apps, however all the data inside the apps looks the same with the dict layout:

```py
test_data = {"appName": {"id": "123", "stages": {"dev": [{"request.cpu": 1000}, {"request.memory": 1024}], "staging": [{"request.cpu": 3200}, {"request.memory": 1024}]}}, "appName2"...}
```

---

I used something like this before:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test_data, orient='index')
df = pd.concat([df.drop(['stages'], axis=1), (df['stages'].apply(pd.Series))], axis=1)
df.index.name = "App"
```

However this wasn't able to split up the list part and also the stages were now in columns so not how i wanted it to look..

Any help much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest solution would be to iterate the rows prior to loading it with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

test_data = {"appName": {"id": "123", "stages": {"dev": [{"request.cpu": 1000}, {"request.memory": 1024}], "staging": [{"request.cpu": 3200}, {"request.memory": 1024}]}}, "appName2": {"id": "456", "stages": {"dev": [{"request.cpu": 1000}, {"request.memory": 1024}], "staging": [{"request.cpu": 3200}, {"request.memory": 1024}]}}}


rows = []

for app, app_data in test_data.items():
    for stage, stage_data in app_data["stages"].items():
        row = {
            "App": app,
            "id": app_data["id"],
            "stages": stage
        }
        for metric in stage_data:
            metric_name, metric_value = list(metric.items())[0]
            row[metric_name] = metric_value
        rows.append(row)

df = pd.json_normalize(rows)

# Reorder columns 
df = df[["App", "id", "stages", "request.cpu", "request.memory"]]
```

Output:

|  | App | id | stages | request.cpu | request.memory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | appName | 123 | dev | 1000 | 1024 |
| 1 | appName | 123 | staging | 3200 | 1024 |
| 2 | appName2 | 456 | dev | 1000 | 1024 |
| 3 | appName2 | 456 | staging | 3200 | 1024 |